# проблема с адаптацией

Tags: css, адаптивность

Проблема в том, что на айфоне сайт выглядит не как на ПК. Медиа запросы поставил, -webkit- поставил, -webkit-appearance: none; поставил. Но всёравно одна кнопка input выглядит совершенно по-другому. Можете подсказать на что ещё обратить внимание.

Comment: А код не запостил в вопрос.

Comment: user-select: none;   white-space: pre;  align-items: flex-start;  box-sizing:border-box;                  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;                                                                                                      letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;                                                                                                    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical; Извиняюсь за вид

Comment: А сама проблема с border-radius он появляется, хотя я его не ставил